# Problem with set initialValues for checkboxes in react-hook-form. In Inputs, dropdowns works great. Why?

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox, parameters, react-hook-form

here is my example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fa1w2w

I have problem, because i want set initialParameters **editData.fields** to checkboxes that these tags will choosed at the beginning and will display in our input.

For the moment it work, that we can choose tags and save what we choosed.

I want display tags which are in object **editData** in **data.js** file

Anyone know answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
<CheckboxComp
      options={dataEnglish}
      label="English"
      name="english"
      setIsChecked={setIsChecked}
      defaultValue={editData.fields.English_Level}
    />
    <CheckboxComp
      options={dataTitle}
      label="Title"
      name="title"
      setIsChecked={setIsChecked}
      defaultValue={editData.fields.Title}
    />
```

.....

```
<Select
      components={animatedComponents}
      isMulti
      options={options}
      onChange={e => onChangeFunc(e)}
      defaultValue={{label: defaultValue}}
    />
```

It works